# To print follow like this from text array

Tags: arrays, text

Print, for each data set that is input, the average to four decimal places. This average should be preceded each time by “For Competitor #X, the average score is ”, where X denotes the competitor’s position (starting with 1) in the input file.

Output to screen for above input file:

For Competitor #1, the average is 5.8625

For Competitor #2, the average is 0.0000

For Competitor #3, the average is 1.0000

file:///C:/Users/tram/Downloads/gym.PNG

go this link this is my code and it printed.

For Competitor #0, the average is 0

For Competitor #0, the average is 0

For Competitor #0, the average is 0

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention in which language do you want it.

In javascript you have:

var num=5.11234123
num.toFixed(4) // "5.1123"

Comment: I want to find the average from text file  file:///C:/Users/lehoang5183/Pictures/txt.PNG                                          and print like this                                                                                 the average is 5.8625
the average is 0.0000
 the average is 1.0000